# What is the difference between these Debian ISOs?

Tags: debian, iso

On [the page where you can download 32-bit Debian DVDs](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.7.0/i386/iso-dvd/), there are three different ISO images listed:

```
debian-7.7.0-i386-DVD-1.iso        2014-10-18 14:23  3.7G  
debian-7.7.0-i386-DVD-2.iso        2014-10-18 14:23  4.4G  
debian-7.7.0-i386-DVD-3.iso        2014-10-18 14:23  4.3G
```

What is the difference between these different ISOs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian contains too much software for a single DVD. Therefore the packages are split up on three different DVDs. All the basics are on the first DVD and all the more "exotic" packages on the last one.

Usually you only use the first DVD to set up a base system and download everything else from the servers. But if you are in a complete offline situation you can use all three DVD and when trying to install things, debian will ask you for the needed DVD.

Answer (score 0):

The one labelled -1 is DVD 1 of 3.  The one labelled -2 is DVD 2 of 3.  The one labelled -3 is DVD 3 of 3.

Comment: You mean we are back to the old _"Level 12 complete. Please insert CD #2 to continue the game."_?

Comment: I don't use Debian much, but this has been quite common in RHEL / CentOS land as far back as I can remember.  If Debian is packaging similarly, the most common software will be on the first dvd.  Depending on what you install, you may only need the first one.

Comment: And if you have a network connection, you hardly need even that. Getting the base system installed from installation media is a fairly lightweight process. Burning a CD or DVD you only use once is rather wasteful anyway.